# How to properly render to two quads in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am creating 2D OpenGL app that is composed of two quads, and two diffrent shader programs associated.

Quad A (big on the left) is main one and has multiple textures associated, quad B small on the right is supposed to have only one texture associated.

First I bind the main quad, prepare all of the textures... all works well.

Next I bind second quad with another shader program (the same vertex shader but diffrent fragment shader)

code

```
glLinkProgram(shader_program_words)
glUseProgram(shader_program_words)

glAttachShader(shader_program_words, fragment_shader_words)
glAttachShader(shader_program_words, vertex_shader)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_words)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Main.ShadersAndVerticiesForText.verticesB_size, Main.ShadersAndVerticiesForText.verticesB, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

encodeDataFromDataBuffer()//glVertexAttribPointer,glEnableVertexAttribArray ...
```

image
[image]

right is green as it should be then I update the texture associated with quad B

```
  glActiveTexture(textSpec.actTextrureNumb); # active proper texture unit before binding
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textSpec.ID); 
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,xoffset,yoffset, widthh, heightt, GL_RED_INTEGER, textSpec.OpGlType, data)
```

basicRender(window)# draw triangles, swap buffers

All works as It should I het color change

[image]

Next I get back to the main quad

```
glUseProgram(shader_program)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_main)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Main.ShadersAndVerticies.vertices), Main.ShadersAndVerticies.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
encodeDataFromDataBuffer()//glVertexAttribPointer,glEnableVertexAttribArray ...
basicrender(window)// swap buffers and drraw triangles
```

It works as It should for main quad but the quad B on the right gets back to initial color - and it is NOT intended

[image]

So I try to reactivate quad B and make it all violet (texture modification code identical as above)

```
glLinkProgram(shader_program_words)
glUseProgram(shader_program_words)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_words)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Main.ShadersAndVerticiesForText.verticesB_size, Main.ShadersAndVerticiesForText.verticesB, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

encodeDataFromDataBuffer()
```

[image]

So now I got random data - that should be displayed on the left on the right, and in quad A nothing. As I see switching of shaders works well. but fo some reason data do not go into texture of Quad B after It got to quad A.
I tried also clearing color buffer and binding to 0 texture before switching between quads yet it did not helped

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.1 , 1.0)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I will deeply appriciate any help as this is very puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok when I was writing it I figured it out so line

glLinkProgram(shader_program_words) - if invoked more then one - and i invoked it every time when I switched between quads was root ot the problem